# Prove that limits can be used for asymptotic analysis

Tags: limits, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

True or false:

If f(n)=$\Theta$(g(n)), then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$$ 
exists and is equal to some real number.

I'm not sure what needs to be done to demonstrate this. I do understand the laws of limits and properties of limits.

Comment: It's not true. The quotient is bounded, but it need not have  a limit.

Comment: You need more hypothesis to show that the limit exists, otherwise you can only say that the sequence is bounded (hence it has finite $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$)

Comment: The REVERSE of your statement is true: if $\lim f/g$ exists and is nonzero then $f = \Theta(g)$.  Maybe that's what you were asked to show instead?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Unforutnately, no. I was asked to solve a specific question and I copied it verbatim from the textbook.

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: @Did "Discrete Mathematics" - Richard Johnsonbaugh, 7th edition

Comment: Aren't you required to determine *whether the implication holds or not*? This is what a version of the book asks to do as exercise 52 of chapter 3 (page 181).

Comment: This is from chapter four, section three, exercise 80, page 210. It's a true/false question. If false, provide a counter-example.

Comment: "It's a true/false question."  That is information which should not be omitted when posting a question like this.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I apologize. I updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an expansion on the perfect comments of Daniel and Crostul. Consider the function:

$$\begin{cases}f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N \\
2k\mapsto 3k \\ 2k+1\mapsto 2k\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases} g: \Bbb N\to\Bbb N \\ n\mapsto n\end{cases}$$

This sequence has $f=\Theta(g)$ by definiting, because

$$|f(n)|\le 2|g(n)|$$ for every $n$, and similarly for every $n$.
$$|g(n)|\le 2|f(n)|$$

Now, for a limit to exist, we need that the value of ${f(n)\over g(n)}$ approaches some number as $n\to\infty$.

However, if $n$ is even, the ratio

$${f(2k)\over g(2k)}={3k\over 2k}={3\over 2}$$

and if $n$ is odd, the ratio is

$${f(2k+1)\over g(2k+1)}={2k\over 2k+1}\stackrel{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 1$$

Formally this is written

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} {f\over g} = {3\over 2} \\ \liminf_{n\to\infty} {f\over g} = 1$$

because the "biggest" limit you could get is ${3\over 2}$ and the "smallest" is $1$, but you don't need to know the terminology for that.

In either case, the limit does not exist for the same reason

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin x$$

does not:  it never approaches anything, it just bounces back and forth between two values.

---

**Addendum:** I chose this function because it actually has non-trivial computations for limits. If you want the "pocket" answer, it's even easier:

Let $f(n) = 1$ no matter what $n$ is and let $g(n) = (-1)^n$ so that

$$|f(n)|\le |g(n)|\le |f(n)|$$

immediately verifying $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$, but the limit of the ratio bounces back and forth between $\pm 1$ forever.

Comment: I will need to look into the formal definition of limit superior and limit inferior as I'm not familiar with them. I was asked to prove this question in order to use limits in asymptotic analysis, and the explanation you provided (although I'm not blaming you) doesn't shine a light on why this proof is necessary for using limits in asymptotic analysis.

Comment: @douglas I've expanded my answer, take a look and see if this at least explains why this particular problem is false.

Comment: I appreicate the expanded explanation, and I think I understand your proof. I'm still puzzled why my professor would state "THIS IS THE SINGLE CASE WHERE A LIMIT CAN GIVE YOU ANY INORMATION ABOUT THE COMPARATIVE GROWTH OF THE FUNCTIONS f and g," (caps are her emphasis).

Comment: Well, I mean there are other notations like

$$f\sim g$$ which is defined to mean

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {f(n)\over g(n)}=1$$

which is especially common in number theory, in that case things can be said, but just $\Theta$ is a different story. I'd bring this up with the professor and see what she/he says.

Comment: That addendum makes it even more clear. Thank you.